# SQL não funciona em outro dispositivo após publicar na web

Tags: c#, sql

Porque minha página não consegue executar consultas ao banco quando ela está publicada na web e sendo utilizadas de outros dispositivos (computadores e smartphone em rede)?

Se eu a utilizo do próprio computador (servidor), eu consigo acessar normalmente. Seria alguma configuração do SQL server que esteja barrando o acesso?

O servidor roda em Windows 7 (IIS 7) SQL Server 2008 RC2

```
connectionStrings: 
name="conexao" connectionString="server=192.168.1.110\\DIEGO-PC,1433;;database=corretor;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Lembrando que todos os dispositivos estão na mesma rede.

Comment: @LucasNunes, por favor, não use `código` para nomes próprios (SQL). Os batsticks devem ser usados somente para **código** e assemelhados (nome de arquivo, paths, URLs).

Comment: @brasofilo Ok! Não vai se repetir.

Comment: Quando você diz "publicada na web", quer dizer que o IIS está em um servidor externo, e você quer que ele acesse seu SQL Server local? Sua configuração de conexão só funciona se o IIS e o SQL estiverem na mesma rede.

Comment: Não, o ISS está na minha máquina mesmo. E todos os dispositivos que estão acessando ele estão na mesma rede. Porem somente o proprio servidor consegue acessar todas as funções que necessitam de acesso ao banco.

Comment: Que erro dá? Certeza que é o SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, geralmente não é boa prática dar acesso direto ao banco de dados em um celular, a menos que você tenha um problema muito peculiar a resolver. O ideal normalmente é que o celular acesse um serviço na rede. Esse serviço seria hospedado em um servidor com acesso ao banco de dados.

Fora isso - você está usando a **segurança integrada do Windows** (`Integrated Security=True;`). Existe uma probabilidade bastante alta (eu diria 99,999 e mais alguns noves porcento de chance) de que o usuário logado em seu celular **não seja o mesmo usuário logado no PC**. Eu diria inclusive que, se for um iPhone, você está logado com uma conta da Apple, e se for Android, o usuário loga no Google, Facebook ou algum outro provedor de identidade.

Se você quiser realmente logar no banco de dados com o telefone (e eu repito que isso em geral não é recomendável), você precisa utilizar outro esquema de segurança, como um que pede nome de usuário e senha. Você precisa configurar o banco para aceitar autenticação que não seja a integrada com Windows, e precisa passar o nome de usuário e senha na string de conexão.

Certifique-se também de que o celular consegue alcançar o servidor pela rede. Mesmo estando na mesma rede, a conexão pode ser negada devido as suas configurações (i.e.: firewall bloqueando a porta 1433 - seu PC pode não te esse problema por ser o próprio servidor - celular não fazendo parte do domínio/grupo de trabalho etc.).

Comment: Acho que me expressei errado. Não é que eu queira dar acesso do banco ao meu "Iphone", e sim que ao acessar o site publicado eu consiga acessar todas as funções do meu site, como login, buscas e inserções de dados. 

Contudo vou me certificar de alterar o modo de acesso ao banco, agora incluindo Login e Senha. De resto eu já fiz, liberei portas, etc... Quando eu tiver o resultado eu aviso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou. Removi o "Integrated Security=True;" e coloquei um User Id e Password na connection string. Obrigado!